# How does one add a user to a git remote repository?

Tags: git

I inherited a remote repository but every time I wish to access the remote(push/pull) I'm always asked for the user and password. I'd like to add authentication details to the repo so as not to authenticate every single time.

**Edit**:
I should clarify the situation in that this a connection between my remote server and a hosted  git repository. (bitbucket)

Comment: question: how do you use GIT ? through IDE / console command / 3rd party tools ? which OS ?

Comment: @Raptor It's a remote repository, so console.

Comment: Assuming the repo isn't managed by something like gitolite, just append your SSH public key to the remote host's `/home/<git-user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @WillVousden I'm trying to get the remote repository to authenticate with a bitbucket account

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "authenticate with a bitbucket account". Git repos are accessed via SSH, which requires access to a user account on the host machine. You can either provide the username and password every time, or you can put your public key on the server so that your SSH client can authenticate automatically with your local private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a git question exactly, but related to how you log into your remote. The first thing you need to do is create a key pair so that you can [log in to the remote without a password](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html).

You then need to make a config file in your `~/.ssh` directory describing how the host connection is set. The file should look something like this:

```
Host myHostName
        User DarkStar1
        Port 22
        Hostname 88.88.88.88
```

Then you can add the origin of you remote using ...

```
git remote add origin myHostName:path/to/repo.git
```

And then you'll be able to pull / push / whatever without authenticating every time

**EDIT:**

Given that you edited your question to mention bitbucket, you can find detailed instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).